# Embeddings between weighted Besov spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, weights, embeddings, besov-spaces

Consider the Besov spaces $B_{p,q}^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for parameters $0<p,q\leq \infty$ and $s\in \mathbb{R}$. The weighted Besov space $B_{p,q}^s(\mathbb{R}^d;\mu)$ is defined for $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f \in B_{p,q}^s(\mathbb{R}^d;\mu) \Leftrightarrow (1 + \lvert \cdot \rvert^2)^{\mu/2} f \in B_{p,q}^s(\mathbb{R}^d).
$$

It is know that the space $B_{p_1,q_1}^{s_1}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mu_1)$ embeds into $B_{p_2,q_2}^{s_2}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mu_2)$ under the conditions
$$
s_2 < s_1, \quad p_1 \leq p_2, \quad s_2 - \frac{d}{p_2} \leq s_1 - \frac{d}{p_1}, \quad \mu_2 \leq \mu_1.
$$
See for instance the chapter 4 of *Function Spaces, Entropy Numbers, Differential Operators*, by Edmunds and Triebel, available [here](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511662201).

**Question:** Are there embeddings results from $B_{p_1,q_1}^{s_1}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mu_1)$ into $B_{p_2,q_2}^{s_2}(\mathbb{R}^d;\mu_2)$ for $p_1 > p_2$?

Inspired by $L_p$-spaces, my guess is that we still have similar results, with the cost of a stronger condition on the weights, something like $\mu_2 \leq \mu_1 - d(1/p_2 - 1/p_1)$, remarking that $d(1/p_2 - 1/p_1) > 0$ in this case. However, I couldn't find a precise statement of that type. I am looking for a good reference for this question.